# Match complete path of a URL to redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I want to redirect a path and all subfolders under this path.

For Example ich want to match the URLs

https://www.joka.de/produktfinder

https://www.joka.de/produktfinder/foo

https://www.joka.de/produktfinder/foo/bar/test.html

The following code works only for the /productfinder but not for productfinder/test

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*joka.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/produktfinder* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.jordan-kassel.de/ausbildung.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the solution

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*joka.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/produktfinder(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.jordan-kassel.de/ausbildung.html [L,R=301]
```